# New DocumentRoot for virtual host dosent work

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I installed xampp and it worked by run apache at localhost and default document root (/Applecations/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs)

After set a new virtual host for mydomain.com and document root: (/Users/myusername/Public/Sites/myProjectFolder) it workes but goes to document root address:(/Applecations/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs) and new document root dosent work

my httpd-vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myusername/Public/Sites/myProjectFolder"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/mydomain.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/mydomain.com-access_log" common
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
        <Directory "/Users/myusername/Public/Sites/myProjectFolder">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you include the httpd-vhosts.conf file in your top-level conf. It will show the default site in cases where nothing matches in the vhosts.

Comment: And, what did you type in as your URL? Perhaps you need to consider adding a bit more info to you question to give us a better chance to help you

Comment: What does you r control panels/ apache logs say? To make sure there are no syntax errors you can run httpd -t in the console